# How to count NA's in aggregate function of a group by using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, series

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'stud_id' : [101, 101, 101, 101, 
                  101, 101, 101, 101],
     'sub_code' : ['CSE01', 'CSE01', 'CSE01', 
                   'CSE01', 'CSE02', 'CSE02',
                   'CSE02', 'CSE02'],
     'ques_date' : ['13/11/2020', '10/1/2018','11/11/2017', '27/03/2016', 
                '13/05/2010',  '10/11/2008','11/1/2007', '27/02/2006'],
     'resp_date' : [np.nan, '11/1/2018','14/11/2017', '29/03/2016', 
                np.nan, np.nan,np.nan,'28/02/2006'],
     'marks' : [77, 86, 55, 90, 
                65, 90, 80, 67]}
)
df['ques_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ques_date'])
df['resp_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['resp_date'])
df['date_diff'] = (df['resp_date'] - df['ques_date']).dt.days
```

I would like to do the below

a) For every `stud_id` and `sub_code` combination, get the avg `date_diff`.

b) For every `stud_id` and `sub_code` combination, get the avg number of `NA`. `NAs` indicate the lack of response. for ex: `stud_id = 101` AND `sub_code = CSE01` combination has `1 NA out of 4 records, resulting in 1/4 = 0.25.

I tried the below but not sure how to get the avg `NA` in aggregate function

```
df.groupby(['stud_id','sub_code']).agg(stud_total_records = ('stud_id','count'),
                                            avg_resp_time = ('date_diff','mean'),
                                            lack_resp_pct = (df.groupby(['stud_id','sub_code'])['resp_date'].isna().sum()).reset_index(name='NA_cnt')['NA_cnt']/stud_total_records)
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by datediff? `diff` applied to datetimes?

Comment: updated the code for date_diff

Comment: I don't understand why avg_resp_time is 9 and 1? Why not 12 and 1 or 9 and 0.25?

Comment: resp_time is 9 for subj_id = 101 because if you add up all the corresponding `date_diff` values and divide by total number of rows for that student (and for that subject), we get only 9..(36/4 = 9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Use lazy groups:

```
grp = df.groupby(['stud_id', 'sub_code'])

out = grp.agg(stud_total_records = ('stud_id', 'count'),
              avg_resp_time = ('date_diff', 'mean'),
              lack_resp_pct = ('date_diff', lambda x: sum(x.isna()) / df['date_diff'].count())) \
         .reset_index()
print(out)

# Output
   stud_id sub_code  stud_total_records  avg_resp_time  lack_resp_pct
0      101    CSE01                   4           12.0           0.25
1      101    CSE02                   4            1.0           0.75
```

---

**Old answer**
Try:

```
out = df.groupby(['stud_id','sub_code']).agg(stud_total_records = ('stud_id', 'count'),
                                            avg_resp_time = ('date_diff', 'mean'))

out['lack_resp_pct'] = df[df['date_diff'].isna()].value_counts(['stud_id', 'sub_code'], normalize=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> out.reset_index()
   stud_id sub_code  stud_total_records  avg_resp_time  lack_resp_pct
0      101    CSE01                   4           12.0           0.25
1      101    CSE02                   4            1.0           0.75
```

Comment: may I check why do you have this? `sum(df['date_diff'].isna()` when you could have just used the total no of records for that stud and subj combination

Comment: thanks, upvoted. But I guess there is some issue with the answer it doesn't work correctly for `old` approach

Comment: What is the problem? Does the `update` work as expected?. I can remove the old one.

Comment: may I know why do you use `sum(df['date_diff'].isna())))` instead of count of records?.

Comment: By habit :) I always use sum with boolean and forget `count`. You're right, I updated my answer.

Comment: The count can also be across any column Right? I mean I can do count on `stu_id` as well?  `df['stud_id'].count()` or `df['subj_id'].count()